# Draw right triangular commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I was wondering how to draw the commutative diagram of the following figure. The closest I could get from previous posts is given in the code below, but it is not quite right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & X \arrow[dr,"a_i"] \\
        X|S \arrow[ur,"\pi"] \arrow[rr,"\hat{a}_i"] && R
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it.

Remove the `&` from the first row. You want the `X` to be in the first column above the `X|S` and remove one of the `&` in the second row.

Of course, you need to adjust the directional statements then as well.

The `dr` becomes `d`, the `rr` becomes `r` and the `ur` would become `r`.

But since you want that arrow to go from `X` to `X|S` you ought to put the `\arrow[d, "\pi"]` there (or `\arrow[u, "\pi", leftarrow]` in the `X|S` cell if that makes more sense from a syntactial point of view).

I've also added a `'` after the `"\hat{a}_i"` statement so that the label is placed on the other side of the arrow.
The same applied for the `\pi` label in case you construct the arrow from `X` to `X|S`.

---

The body of the `tikzcd` environment can be treated like a `tabular`/`array` where `&` separates the columns.

The `\arrow` macro starts an arrow in that cell with the target according to the directional shortcut. (Unless keys like `from` and `to` are used.)

By default, all arrows use the `rightarrow` style which can be inverted by using `leftarrow`. For more on this, I'd recommend reading the [manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-cd/0).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    X \arrow[dr, "a_i"] \arrow[d, "\pi"']\\
    X|S \arrow[r,"\hat{a}_i"'] & R
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That's great! Thank you @Qrrbrbirlbel.
Would you please let me know how to make it wider (horizontally), and maybe longer (vertically)?

Comment: @AEW Use the keys `column sep` and `row sep`. They are explained very well in the manual. Besides normal dimensions, they also have some predefined ones like `row sep=large`.

Comment: OK, thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider also to use `xy` package that have the same structure of `tikz-cd` and also the same tips. See the output and the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{
X\ar[dr]^{a_i}  \ar[d]_{\pi}  \\
X/S \ar[r]_{\hat{a}_i} & R}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### follow up

You can increase o reduce the rows `@R=2cm` or the columns `@C=2.5cm`. (`2cm`,`2.5cm`) are the measures.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix@R=2cm@C=2.5cm{
X\ar[dr]^{a_i}  \ar[d]_{\pi}  \\
X/S \ar[r]_{\hat{a}_i} & R}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Sebastiano. Would it be possible to make it wider (horizontally) and longer (vertically)?

Comment: @aew yes Is possible

Comment: Would you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: @AEW Now you can see the variations in the second code.

Comment: Thank you, @Sebastiano.

Comment: @AEW You're welcome. :-)